# Securing site port, 8443, with SSL

Tags: security, port

I have my hosting server at :8443. When I try to open it  then SSL generates error saying site is not secure. So how can I add SSL so that it wont gives that error[image: ecuring port through SSL]

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should ask on [sf] instead.

Comment: It says "invalid CA" (certificate authority). You need to buy a certificate from a source that your browser can trust.